# Navigation bar odd behavior after giving it a fixed position in the css file

Tags: html, css

I made a navigation bar with a dropdown and was working fine until i added the "position: fixed;" statement in the css file. Once I did that the dropdown either isn't coming up when the mouse hovers over the designated button or is coming up off screen. Note the parent button reacts to the mouse hover fine in terms of color changes, that's why i think the dropdown is coming up off screen.

EDIT: i realized that the dropdown appears in the ul element and i can scroll within it to view the list. It's not appearing as an actual dropdown over the content on the page but within the navbar itself.

Here's my code:

```css
ul.navbar {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #ffb90f;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 48px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}

.navbar li {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
}

li a,
.dropbtn {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover,
dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #FFC63D;
}

li.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #FFF3D5;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 100px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  margin-left: 8.7%;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: #FFBE1E;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ffb90f;
  color: white;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <ul class="navbar">
    <li id="navbar" style=" margin-left: 3%; width:22%"><a href="homepage.php" class="dropbtn">Home</a></li>
    <li id="navbar" style=" width: 50%; text-align: center"><img src="logo.png" width="45px" height="45px" style="margin: 0"></li>
    <li id="navbar" class="dropdown" style="float: right; margin-right: 3%; width: 21%; text-align: right">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Jump to...</a>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Item1</a>
        <a href="#">Item2</a>
      </div>
    </li>


  </ul>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update css and remove the `overflow` to properties  `ul.navbar`from your css and add `position:relative` and remove `width:21%;` to below html

```
<li id="navbar" class="dropdown" style="float: right; margin-right: 3%; text-align: right; position:relative;">
```

css part

```
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #FFF3D5;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 100px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  margin-left: 8.7%;
  left:0px; /* Add this you can change it as your need */
}
```

working fiddle

**[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0zvfvm6q/22/)**

```css
ul.navbar {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #ffb90f;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: auto;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}

.navbar li {
  display: inline-block;
}

li a,
.dropbtn {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover,
dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #FFC63D;
}

li.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #FFF3D5;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 100px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  margin-left: 8.7%;
  left:0px;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: #FFBE1E;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ffb90f;
  color: white;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="navbar">
  <li id="navbar" style=" margin-left: 3%; width:22%"><a href="homepage.php" class="dropbtn">Home</a></li>
  <li id="navbar" style=" width: 50%; text-align: center"><img src="logo.png" width="45px" height="45px" style="margin: 0"></li>
  <li id="navbar" class="dropdown" style="float: right; margin-right: 3%; text-align: right; position:relative;">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Jump to...</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Item1</a>
      <a href="#">Item2</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/0zvfvm6q/19/ working fiddle fine. just copy paste the css part which i posted.

Comment: it worked! kind of haha the list appears but not under the button and the home button on the left side of the bar is in improperly placed after removing the overflow statements. it doesn't show in the fiddle though.

Comment: yeah i saw that it's just not reacting properly and it isn't showing up on the fiddle. The "Jump to.." button is in the top right corner which is correct, but the "Home" button is in the lower left and it needs to be in the top left. because its its seemingly in a lower section it'd resizing the width the bar.

Comment: I add a "float: left;" to the home button and that fixed it, and added a "right: 0;" to the dropdown content and got it going. Thank a lot for you help!

Answer (score 0):

Remove `overflow` from `.navbar`

```css
ul.navbar {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #ffb90f;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 48px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}

.navbar li {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
}

li a,
.dropbtn {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover,
dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #FFC63D;
}

li.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #FFF3D5;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 100px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  margin-left: 8.7%;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: #FFBE1E;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ffb90f;
  color: white;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <ul class="navbar">
    <li id="navbar" style=" margin-left: 3%; width:22%"><a href="homepage.php" class="dropbtn">Home</a></li>
    <li id="navbar" style=" width: 50%; text-align: center"><img src="logo.png" width="45px" height="45px" style="margin: 0"></li>
    <li id="navbar" class="dropdown" style="float: right; margin-right: 3%; width: 21%; text-align: right">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Jump to...</a>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Item1</a>
        <a href="#">Item2</a>
      </div>
    </li>


  </ul>

</body>
```